# Start Site Workflow with Read permission

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, workflow, permissions

I have a Sharepoint Site Workflow 2013.Users with read permissions should be able to start this Workflow. Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to specifically grant the user permissions for that library to a higher permissions level.  Read-only users are not able to start workflows.  Impersonation steps will not work either because the option to start the workflow will still be grayed out.

[Read only user to start workflow](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/3b9627ee-da99-4146-bc51-d209f3488aa0/read-only-user-to-start-workflow)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Flat Banana above.  Create a custom permission type which will appear in the same list as read only.